# Nexus OSS 3 - UI not showing proxied components

Tags: maven, nexus, nexus3

I've installed a fresh new **Nexus Repository OSS 3.3.2-02**. It has a `maven-central` repository pre-configured. Without changing anything I just grabbed URL for accessing this proxy repository and added it to my local M2 settings.

When I try building some project, my dependencies are correctly fetched and project built. Here is a look of maven client logs:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building jiraBootcamp 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.atlassian.jira:jira-api:jar:7.2.2 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.atlassian.plugin:atlassian-spring-scanner-annotation:jar:2.1.1 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.atlassian.activeobjects:activeobjects-plugin:jar:1.2.3 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.atlassian.plugins.rest:atlassian-rest-common:jar:1.0.2 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.atlassian.sal:sal-api:jar:2.6.0 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: https://devtools.morosystems.cz/nexus/repository/maven-central/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.16.4/lombok-1.16.4.pom
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.16.4/lombok-1.16.4.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.16.4/lombok-1.16.4.pom (2 KB at 10.5 KB/sec)
```

The problem is that when I browse Nexus UI I would expect **Lombok** library to be:

- present in Components/Assets view,
- searchable.

However, this is not working as the views are empty and search finds nothing.

Please, can you help me find what is wrong? It is the first time I configure Nexus OSS 3 so solution may be very simple.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your maven log shows that the component wasn't downloaded from Nexus:

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.16.4/lombok-1.16.4.pom

Set up Nexus as a mirror of all repositories in Maven as outlined here:

http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference3/maven.html#maven-sect-single-group

That will prevent Maven from accessing repositories other than Nexus.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and pointing me in the right direction. There was indeed a mistake in my settings.xml file. Now I can see download is performing solely against my Nexus. The only problem is that the requests are now `ReasonPhrase: Forbidden.` So it seems the authentication is OK, but authorization fails. I will check Nexus settings as soon as having more time for the problem solving.